# Manipulate every second row as a particular column value in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where every second row from column `X1`(which is the address) should going to column `x3` in its previous row. Below is the actaul dataframe structure.How could I do that in `r`.

```
structure(list(X1 = c("(512) Brewing Company", "407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"0 Mile Brewing Company", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"10 Barrel Brewing", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"
), X2 = c("(512) Brewing Company", "407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"0 Mile Brewing Company", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"10 Barrel Brewing", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"
), X3 = c("-", "407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"-", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"-", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"), X4 = c("-", 
"407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"-", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"-", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"), X5 = c("3.84", 
"Brewery, Bar", "-", "Brewery", "-", "Brewery, Bar, Eatery"), 
    X6 = c("37", "Brewery, Bar", "4", "Brewery", "0", "Brewery, Bar, Eatery"
    )), row.names = 4:9, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll always have even number of rows -

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("(512) Brewing Company", "407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"0 Mile Brewing Company", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"10 Barrel Brewing", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"
), X2 = c("(512) Brewing Company", "407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"0 Mile Brewing Company", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"10 Barrel Brewing", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"
), X3 = c("-", "407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"-", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"-", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"), X4 = c("-", 
"407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"-", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"-", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States"), X5 = c("3.84", 
"Brewery, Bar", "-", "Brewery", "-", "Brewery, Bar, Eatery"), 
    X6 = c("37", "Brewery, Bar", "4", "Brewery", "0", "Brewery, Bar, Eatery"
    )), row.names = 4:9, class = "data.frame")

df$X3 <- NA_character_

df$X3[seq(1, nrow(df), by = 2)] <- df$X1[seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2)]
```

---

Another generalized approach (irrespective of number of rows) using `dplyr` package -

```
library(dplyr)
df$X3 <- lead(df$X1, 1)
df$X3[seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2)] <- NA_character_
```